# New automaton that runs two others step by step?

Tags: automata

If I have two automatons for two languages ($M_1, M_2, L_1,L_2$ respectively), what would be the procedure to mix them by defining a new automaton such that the new automaton would accept the words $\theta_1\sigma_1\theta_2\sigma_2...\theta_n\sigma_n $ where $\theta_1 ... \theta_n \in L_1 , \sigma_1 ... \sigma_n \in L_2 $? By making it run from $M_1$ to $M_2$ to $M_1$ again to $M_2$ again and finally to an accepting state of $M_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define what kind of automaton you want. I will use finite state automatons. Let $M_1$ have state set $Q_1$, symbol set $S_1$, initial state $i_1 \in Q_1$, transition function $t_1: Q_1×S_1 \mapsto Q_1$ and accepting states $A_1 \subseteq Q_1$. Similarly define the components of $M_2$.

We can construct the machine you want with:

- states $Q_1×Q_2 + Q_2×Q_1$,
- symbols $S_1 + S_2$,
- initial state $(i_1, i_2)$,
- transition function left as exercise, :-)
- accepting states $A_1×A_2$.

I hope you can finish it from here.

Comment: What does the sign $+$ mean in $Q_1 x Q_2 + Q_2 x Q_1$?

Comment: It means the disjoint sum. An element of $A+B$ is either an element of $A$ or an element of $B$ but not both. If A and B intersect, then we must magic up some injections to avoid a collision.

Comment: Ugh, looks like I might have misread your question. I thought you meant $\theta_1\ldots\theta_n$ is a single word of $L_1$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It is, your understanding is fine.
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $M_1$ and $M_2$ are deterministic finite state machines, form a [non-deterministic finite automaton with ε moves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton_with_%CE%B5-moves) as shown below and then apply the [powerset construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to get a deterministic one.

[image]

Comment: This is great.
Thanks.

Comment: This automaton solves a different problem in which $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n$ are each words of $L_1$.